#  Is there a version of character sheaves for non reductive algebraic groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Lusztig's theory of character sheaves gives a geometric
way to obtain character tables of finite groups of Lie type (coming
from reductive groups). I am interested to know if there is a similar
theory for other kinds of algebraic groups. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boyarchenko and Drinfeld have developed a theory of character sheaves for unipotent groups. See [*A motivated introduction to character sheaves and the orbit method for unipotent groups in positive characteristic*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609769) for an introduction (as well as subsequent papers by Boyarchenko and Boyarchenko-Drinfeld).